# Highcharts issue with max value (100) - React

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

When I set the value of data inside a highchart to 100, the line breaks, here is what I mean:
[image]

[image]

See how there when two values are 100, the line kinda breaks and it is not the same width as values that are not 100, meaning it probably breaks at the top for some reason. I tried everything to fix this, I tried to fix it using properties from official documentation: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/ , but with no luck.

Here is my code:

```
function PopularityGraph({ data }) {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ lineChart: {} });

  const splitEmptyData = series => {
    const index = series.findIndex(item => item.y !== 0);
    if (index > 0) {
      const dataNonEmpty = series.slice(index);
      const dataEmpty = series.slice(0, index).map(item => ({ ...item, y: dataNonEmpty[0].y }));
      return [{ data: dataNonEmpty }, { data: dataEmpty, dashStyle: "dot", states: { hover: { enabled: false } } }];
    } else {
      return [{ data: series }];
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const regressionResult = regression.linear(
      Object.keys(data).map((item, index) => {
        return [index, data[item]];
      })
    );

    const split = splitEmptyData(
      Object.keys(data).map(item => {
        return { x: parseInt(item), y: data[item] };
      })
    );

    setState({
      ...state,
      lineChart: {
        chart: {
          type: "line",
        },
        title: {
          text: null,
        },
        xAxis: {
          lineWidth: 0,
          type: "datetime",
          tickLength: 0,
          labels: {
            y: 30,
            formatter: function() {
              return dayjs.unix(this.value).format("MMM 'YY");
            },
          },
        },
        yAxis: [
          {
            lineWidth: 0,
            max: 100,
            min: 0,
            title: {
              text: "Popularity",
            },
            labels: {
              formatter: function() {
                return shortenNumbers(this.value);
              },
            },
          },
        ],

        plotOptions: {
          series: {
            states: { hover: { enabled: false } },
            marker: {
              enabled: false,
            },
            events: {
              legendItemClick: function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
              },
            },
          },
        },
        legend: {
          enabled: false,
        },
        series: [
          {
            name: "Popularity",
            color: "#19a049",
            ...split[0],
          },
          {
            name: "Popularity",
            color: "#19a049",
            ...split[1],
          },
          {
            marker: { enabled: false },
            showInLegend: false,
            data: Object.keys(data).map((item, index) => {
              return [parseInt(item), index * regressionResult.equation[0] + regressionResult.equation[1]];
            }),
            type: "area",
            fillOpacity: 0.2,
            threshold: -Infinity,
            dashStyle: "dash",
            lineWidth: 1,
            enableMouseTracking: false,
            color: "#acf1c4",
          },
        ],
        tooltip: {
          useHTML: true,
          shared: true,
          crosshairs: {
            color: "#707580",
            dashStyle: "dash",
            width: 1.5,
          },
          formatter: function() {
            return `
            <div class="graph-tooltip has-shadow">
              <time class="year">${dayjs.unix(this.x).format("MMMM")} ${dayjs.unix(this.x).format("YYYY")}</time>
              <div class="channel-value">Popularity: ${
                split[1] && this.points[0].x <= split[1].data[split[1].data.length - 1].x
                  ? "No data available"
                  : "<strong>" + shortenNumbers(this.points[0].y) + "</strong>"
              }</div>
            </div>`;
          },
        },
      },
    });
  }, [data]);

  return (
    <div className="graph">
      <HighchartsReact highcharts={Highcharts} options={state.lineChart} />
    </div>
  );
}

PopularityGraph.propTypes = {
  data: PropTypes.object,
};

export default PopularityGraph;
```

The only "fix" that "works" is when I set the max value to 101 inside yAxis property, but then my graph looks like this:

[image]

Which is not what I want because then not only the axis on the left shows 120 as max value it also is way too moved from the top if you know what I mean.

If anyone knows what is the issue I would gladly appreciate it.

P.S. English is not my primary language therefore I apologize for any grammar mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `clip` option to `false`:

```
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      clip: false
    }
  }
```

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.line.clip

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pgs4yjce/

Another approach would be removing `yAxis.max`, setting `endOnTick` to `false` and `maxPadding` to the adequate value.

```
  yAxis: {
    endOnTick: false,
    maxPadding: 0.05, // sample value
    min: 0,
  }
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/kduycew8/